# Month by week of the year?

Tags: php, datetime, math, calendar

I'm trying to get the number of the month of the year by the number of a week of the year and the year.
So for example week 1 is in january and returns 1, week 6 is in february so I want 2.

I tried to go with `date_parse_from_format('W/Y')` but had no success (it's giving me errors).

Is there any way to go with `date_parse_from_format()` or is there another way?

Comment: How do you propose to cope with weeks that start in one month and end in another?

Comment: They should belong to the month they start in, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Precisely which [week numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week_number#Week_numbering) do you want to use?

Comment: The week numbering system `date('W')` gives back. Which is ISO-8601, beginning on Mondays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print date("m",strtotime("2011-W6-1"));
```

(noting that in 2011, January has six weeks so week 6 (by some definitions) is in month 1).

Comment: Bug, if we test at this time (2017-01-19), this fuction never return correct week of month 2!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a note for the first answer, the week number should be 01-09 for Weeks 1 through 9 (it will always give month 1 if you don't add the leading zero)

```
date("m",strtotime("2011-W06-1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP DateTime objects (which is the preferred way of dealing with dates see links below for more info) you can accomplish it this way:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->setISODate($year,$week);
$month = $dateTime->format('n');
```

Note that the following will not work as week "W" is [not a supported format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters):

```
$month = \DateTime::createFromFormat("W/Y ", "1/2015")->format('n');
```

The format used by this method [is the same supported by the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php#refsect1-function.date-parse-from-format-parameters) you where trying to use `date_parse_from_format`, hence the errors.

- [Why PHP DateTime Rocks](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2012/08/why-php-datetime-rocks/)
- [DateTime class vs. native PHP date-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions)
- [`strtotime` notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)
- [PHP/Architect's Guide to Date and Time Programming (Chapter 2)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981034500)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do, this is also tested and works:

```
function getMonthByNumber($number,$year)
{
    return date("F",strtotime('+ '.$number.' weeks', mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year,-1)));
}

echo getMonthByNumber(27,2011);
```

Hope this helps