# Transform DateTime variable into minutes

Tags: php, date, time

There is the following variable:

```
$datetime = '2012-09-09 01:40';
```

I need to extract hours and minutes, and then to transform them into minutes. In this example, I would need to get 100 (1 hr 40 min = 60 min + 40 min). How can I quickly do this using PHP functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtotime()` and `date()` functions are not recommended anymore. Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class.

```
$datetime = '2012-09-09 01:40';
$d = new DateTime($datetime);
var_dump( $d->format('G') * 60 + $d->format('i') );
```

Comment: Why not? His date string is in standard format, and object declarations, from what I understand, are expensive. I still gave an upvote, because if he had dynamic strings, then he should use `DateTime`, no question.

Comment: @David: because your example won't work anymore if input will be year 2038 or bigger. try to set year to 2060 in your answer, and see what the output will be...

Comment: Also: [DateTime class vs. native PHP date-functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8605563/612202)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '2012-09-09 01:40';
$epoch = strtotime($string);
echo date('i', $epoch) + (60 * date('H', $epoch));
```

Outputs **100**

Basically what happens here is the string date gets converted to [Unix/Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Then, using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it adds the number of minutes (i) to 60 times the number of hours (h).

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = strtotime('2012-09-09 01:40');
$hour = date('H',$datetime);
$min = date('i',$datetime);
echo ($hour*60 + $min);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` like this:

```
$parts=preg_split("/(\d\d):(\d\d)/",$datetime,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$mins=($parts[1]*60)+$parts[2];
```

Now $mins=100 when `$datetime` is like in your post

Comment: This is faster than first transforming to a DateTime object. More sensitive to changes in the string format, but still, faster.