# PHP: strtototime, how to get a date of last 1 january early then NOW() minus N days/yars?

Tags: php, strtotime

if today is 2016-02-09
minus 3 years (or minus 1095 days)
new date is 2013-02-09
now I need to get a date of last 01 january before 2013-02-09
result 2013-01-01

it should be something like this maybe:
strtotime('last 1 january 1095 days ago')
or
strtotime('first january -3 years')

Comment: `(date('Y') -3) . '-01-01'`?

Comment: It may also need to 01 July or other specific month

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object:

```
$threeYearsAgo = (new DateTime())->modify('-3 years');
$januaryFirst = $threeYearsAgo->format('Y-01-01');
```

or (if your PHP version doesn't support the first example):

```
$threeYearsAgo = new DateTime();
$threeYearsAgo->modify('-3 years');
$januaryFirst = $threeYearsAgo->format('Y-01-01');
```

Comment: Why not just `strtotime("yesterday", strtotime("+ 1 month", $timestamp))` or something like that... :)

Comment: @Smar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions

Comment: @MateiMihai: the reason I don’t like `DateTime` is not because of performance but because it has highly annoying and often useless API, forcing me to use the functions directly to get the stuff done sanely, so I tend not to use the class at any time anyway, to be consistent.

Comment: ...what...? Can you show an example of it being a useless api @Smar

Comment: This exaple does not work properly
for 01 jan it's fine
but in gaves wrong if I needed 1 jule for example

Answer (score 0):

To **output** a date of last 1 january early 3 years then `now()` with **strtotime**, you can simply use this code:

```
echo date( 'Y-01-01', strtotime( "-3 years" ) );
```

To **get** a date timestamp of desired value, you can use this code:

```
$date = strtotime( date( 'Y-01-01', strtotime( "-3 years" ) ) );
```

If you prefer instead to use the `DateTime` class, to **get** the date as desired, you can use this code:

```
$date = new DateTime( '-3 years' );
$date->setDate( $date->format('Y'), 1, 1 );
```