# Formatting the Timestamp in UserSpice

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am a newbie to PhP/MySQL , Just learning things .

I am using Userspice User management framework for my project

In the database there is table called `"users"` and it has a field name `"join_date"` and the field entry will look like `2016-01-01 00:00:00` it is been stored as timestamp at the time of user registration .

To output that i use the following query

```
<?php $user->data()->join_date; ?>
```

The above query as expected outputs `2016-01-01 00:00:00`

But my required output is `January 2016` . So , i tried the following query

```
<?php $user->data()->join_date->format('F Y'); ?>
```

but the page becomes blank . I can understand that the above query has either syntax error or logically wrong. Can you please help me with this please . I might look silly asking these small things, I am just learning stuffs.

Update :

Also i tried the following query now thinking that storing in a value and doing will help but same error of blank page .

```
<?php 
$x = $user->data()->join_date;
$y = $x->format('F-Y');
echo $y;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to format date using `strtotime` function: (replace `$date` with your date variable)

```
$date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00';

echo date('F Y', strtotime($date));
```

output:

```
January 2016
```

Here `DateTime` class is better option:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($date);

echo $datetime->format('F Y');
```

Output:

```
January 2016
```

For more detail have look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Thanks a ton mate . It worked ! . By the way may i know why u mentioned `DateTime` is a better option than `strtotime`.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions or you can search on google for same

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
   $formatted_date = new DateTime($user->data()->join_date);
   echo $formatted_date->format('F Y');
?>
```