# Get month name in PHP from date

Tags: php, date

I have a date in my php function like following:

```
2016-05-17 16:41:51
```

Is there some way for me to get the month name from this date in PHP ?

Comment: `echo date("F", strtotime('2016-05-17 16:41:51'));`

Comment: I think you never tried, at your end : https://eval.in/579273

Comment: The question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date' is about JavaScript, this question is about PHP.

Answer (score 31):

Using the `F` in the date parameter you can get the month name.

```
echo date("F", strtotime('2016-05-17 16:41:51')); //May
```

[More details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: duplicate.. so many answers available with same question in SO. First check for duplicate and flag it.

Comment: @Frayne Konok thank you so much for the quick reply !! :) :) Works like a charm :)

Comment: @RuchishParikh Yes, There are so many questions about the date time.

Comment: Not sure if using spaghetti strtotime in 2016 is the best practice

Comment: @perkes456, before making a question you need to search for the answer ion stack. If you don't find anything than post it.

Comment: @DainisAbols, don't get you, can you please explain a little.

Comment: @FrayneKonok It's probably also just my opinion, but here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions