# Get month names from current month - to the end of the year in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have fetched a current month from my DB which is basically a join date of the user. Lets say the use joined this month and it is May. The code I do to fetch the month name is like this:

```
$months = array();
array_push($months,date("F",strtotime($me['joinTime'])));
```

In this case I add the start month to the array, which in this case is May... Now what I'd like to do is as the months go by, I'd like to add each new month to the array.. So for instance in a few days its June, and when June kicks in, I'll add that Month as well to the array.. So my question here is, how can I get the rest of the month names from the start date (May).

I need June, July, August, September, October, November, December...

If the start month was April I'd add May into the array as well...

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: you need to fixed a last month with year.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that.. Can you reply with an answer so that I can accept it if it works ?

Comment: Your answer is ready.

Comment: You haven't accepted this yet, Although it worked for you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37521867/2815635

Comment: Yes, you need to accept answer after getting help, other wise we will be not available for you for a long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to get he month number and than you need to use a loop through to end of the year that is 12. For each month number you also need the month name so use `DateTime createFromFormat`.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/eONQm)

```
$months = array();
$num = date("n",strtotime($me['joinTime']));
array_push($months, date("F", strtotime('2016-05-17 16:41:51')));

for($i = ($num + 1); $i <= 12; $i++){
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i);
    array_push($months, $dateObj->format('F'));
}

print_r($months); // Array ( [0] => May [1] => June [2] => July [3] => August [4] => September [5] => October [6] => November [7] => December )
```

Comment: Hey thanks it works, just a little fix for the code:  date_create_from_format('!m',$i); DateTime::createFromFormat throws me an error for some reason... The way I wrote here in comment works well! :)

Comment: try with this `\DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i);`, using the front `\` before the `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also put it like

```
$array = array();
array_push($array, date('F')) ;
for ($i=1; $i<=  12 - date('m'); $i++ ){
    array_push($array, date('F', strtotime("+$i months"))) ;
}
print "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we will be using DatePeriod which allows iteration over a set of dates and times, recurring at regular intervals, over a given period.

So we got the end date and we have the start date and then calculated the  interval. And then looping over the period we got the array of months.

```
// current date : 20 Feb 2019

$startDate = new \DateTime('first day of next month');
$endDate = new \DateTime('1st january next year');

$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');

$period = new \DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);

// Start array with current date
$dates = [];

// Add all remaining dates to array
foreach ($period as $date) {
     array_push($dates, $date->Format('F'));
}

// output
print_r($dates); die;

Array ( [0] => March [1] => April [2] => May [3] => June [4] => July [5] => August [6] => September [7] => October [8] => November [9] => December )
```