# How to convert day of a month to dates?

Tags: php, date

How to convert monday or any other day to all future dates of a month in php? Also consider holiday which is stored in database. For example, Monday of October 2019 should produce one date i.e. 28/10/2019 considering today's date is 26/10/2019. But, Monday of November 2019 should produce 4/11/2019, 11/11/2019, 18/11/2019 and 25/11/2019 respectively.

Comment: Can you share some samples of your input and expected output?

Comment: I have added example.

Comment: Why it's got a down vote?

Comment: Probably because you did not post the code you used to try this out. Also can be because it was not worded properly initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is what I could come up with. I have used the capabilities of `DateTime` to read and parse date strings. Let me explain line-by-line.

```
$date = new DateTime("Saturday, November 2019");
$expected_month = $date->format('m');
$day = new DateTime(sprintf('First %s of %s %d', $date->format('l'), $date->format('F'), $date->format('Y')));
$now = new DateTime();
while($day->format('m') == $expected_month) {
    if($day->getTimestamp() >= $now->getTimestamp()) {
        print($day->format('d/m/Y'));
    }
    $day = $day->modify(sprintf("next %s", $date->format('l')));
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**Explanation**

PHP's `[DateTime]` parses these date strings very, very well. For example: `First Sunday of October 2019`, `next Monday`, `next week`, `last Friday` and so on. I have used this capability while coding the above solution.

1. `$date = DateTime("Monday, October 2019");`

This is our input. We want to find all Mondays in October 2019

1. `$expected_month = $date->format('m');`
   We will be using a loop to restrict ourselves to print days only in the selected month. We use `$expected_month` for this purpose.
2. `$day = new DateTime(sprintf('First %s of %s %d', $date->format('l'), $date->format('F'), $date->format('Y')));`

This line assigns the timestamp of the first Monday of the month to `$day`.

3. The `while` loop checks if we are in the current month itself. In its body, we use `next Monday` to fetch the next Monday's date in October and assign it to `$day`.

**UPDATE-1**

Corrected the function to skip dates in the past.

**UPDATE-2**

As per suggestion by @Dharman, used `DateTime` instead of `strtotime` after reading through some good explanations of [why `DateTime` is more preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions)

**UPDATE-3**
Updated code to include today's date also.

Comment: I am getting this error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/test.php on line 6

Comment: I would recommend to use `DateTime` class as much as possible over the old `strtotime`. Once you start using it you will see a lot of benefits.

Comment: @Dharman: Thank you, I recoded it using `DateTime`.

Comment: @y00y.crabbe: Use the latest code and let me know.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you for the solution. But, on a Monday it's excluding that date. Can it be included. I will also give it a try.

Comment: @y00y.crabbe: I did'nt get you fully. Can you paste the input you are trying to give to the code?

Comment: Input-Day of week (Example: Monday), Month and year. But, if today is Monday then the code is excluding today's date. Can it be included.

Comment: @y00y.crabbe: check the updated code and let me know. This was very simple, just replace the `>` with `>=` in the condition.